# How to target the first heading of any type in its parent

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to clean up output from my CMS' Rich text editor and I'd like to space things out nicely. I'm adding a margin-top to all headings within the copy but I'd like to remove that from the first heading.

Although if the first content is a 'p' and not a heading, that won't work. I've has some success with the '+' selector in the past but can't seem to get that going.

```
<div class="body_copy">
    <h5>My Heading here</h5>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>

    <p>
        <img src="images/image1.jpg" alt="">
    </p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

    <h5>Another heading here</h5>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Would be grateful for any of your ideas!

EDIT: I think I have it sort of working if I target every p + h2, p + h3 and apply margin-top to them. Am still interested if there's a better approach though?

Comment: Can you point to the heading element(s) you want selected? If there is a mixture of `h2, h3, h4, h5` do you want only the very first of these selected, or will the first of each type do?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `~` selector. It's less strict compared to the + selector.

```
div > h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
}

div > h1 ~ h1 {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

With the above example, all of the headings in a div apart from the first in the div will have a margin on the top of 20px.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, so in this case I could use div > h1 ~ h1, div > h2 ~ h2, div > h3 ~ h3 etc?

Comment: Yeah, that'd work fine. If you wanted to simplify your CSS, you could give all hx elements a class, then use the same thing, for example div > .hx ~ .hx

Answer (score 0):

According to [CSS2 Selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching) (no [CSS3 selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors) involved in your question... and you better bookmark this two links :), `+` is the Adjacent Sibling Selector (Adjacent Sibling Combinator in CSS3), that will match elements only if absolutely adjacents (one following another, with nothing in the middle).

You may want to consider the [General Sibling Combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators), `E ~ F`, that will match every F element preceeded (but not immediately) by an element E, that will give you more flexibility and hopefully the result you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option, if the heading element will always be the first child of its parent, is:

```
h1, h2, h3 /* ...etc */ {
    margin-top: 1em;
}

h1:first-child, h2:first-child, h3:first-child /* ...etc */ {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

To restrict that to only those headings that are the `:first-child` within, and the immediate children of, the `.body_copy` element, then simply modify the selector:

```
.body_copy > h1,
.body_copy > h2,
.body_copy > h3 /* ...etc */ {
    margin-top: 1em;
}

.body_copy > h1:first-child,
.body_copy > h2:first-child,
.body_copy > h3:first-child /* ...etc */ {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```